# Is passing the entire object really the way to do this?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, dom-events

At [this page](http://es.discovermeteor.com/chapters/creating-posts/), I see this code:

```
post._id = Posts.insert(post);
Router.go('postPage', post);
```

...to load a page based on the _id value.

Is this really what it should be, or should it be instead:

```
var id = Posts.insert(post);
Router.go('postPage', id);
```

?

IOW, why pass the entire object when all that is needed is the id, which is returned from the insert function (quoting from the page linked to above, "*La función insert() devuelve el identificador _id del objeto que se ha insertado en la base de datos*")?

Even if the way shown works (the router is smart enough to extract the id), isn't "my way" better (even though I'm not Sinatra)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. The example code in the blog post you cite won't even work.

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

will fail when passed *post* as a parameter because *this.params._id* is the whole *:_id* parameter, not an extraction of the *_id* from a passed object.